# Error al ejecutar la apk en android studio solo cargan el tab

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Buenas estoy creando mi primera app mobile pero el problema que tengo es que me arroja este mensaje en el logcat

Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).

Y al ejecutar la apk me tira en blanco todo, solo muestra los tabs y el contenido de los tabs esta vacio y cuando le hago click al tab me lanza el mensaje de error, no se que informacion mas puedo entregar (Esta sin firmar)

[Asi se ve el la apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ViAp.png)

[Asi se deberia de ver (esto es lo que ejecuto en el ionic serve --lab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P2zg.png)

He intentado desintalar, actualizar versiones, mas de 3 veces, pero ya no se qué más hacer

Answer (score 0):

El problema indica que no estas realizando la inicialización de Firebase, esto debe realizarse en el método onCreate() de tu activity inicial de la aplicación:

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)


        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)  // * Inicializa Firebase

        ...
        ...
        ...

  }
```